# Why usercontrol outputcache has no Location property?

Tags: asp.net, user-controls, outputcache

I have some questions about OutPutCache to UserControl. I'm a fresher on OutPutCache.

1、I found that I can't set the location property. Where does the UserControl existed?
2、It seems that the  UserControl would inherit outputcache features from the page.
   So how can I set the no-store property to the UserControl individually?
   Such as: I cached a news page, it will be refreshed daily. but I want to get the latest
   views everytime. or I only want to get the login username. What should I do?

I will be very appreciate for your help!
Best Regards,

David Peng

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `<asp:substitution>` control and load UserControl that cannot be cached in [substitution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228212.aspx) control, look at this article about [donut caching](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/28/tip-trick-implement-donut-caching-with-the-asp-net-2-0-output-cache-substitution-feature.aspx).

Since substitution control can just take string and render it you will have to render user control to string and assign that string to substitution control, here are the details [How to use ASP.Net server controls inside of Substitution control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3138192/how-to-use-asp-net-server-controls-inside-of-substitution-control)